I need to design Editext like dashes for Refrral code entry in andriod kotlin
I want xml design for edit text with Dashes to enter the Referral code, below I have mention output.
this is the image
I have tried create a shape for that dash I have tried different approach it not working.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/green" />
            <size android:height="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="18dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:height="2dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/green" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>


<EditText
            android:id="@+id/code1"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ref_background"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext" />

I have added my code above. It's not working how can I do that.
how can I achieve output like that above image which I addeed.

You can try this.
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ABC"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="@color/pink_application"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text_1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/text_1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/text_1"/>

Basically. I will create a view and set it below the Edittext.
Method 2. If you want to use drawable.
You need to edit it to:
solid android:color="@android:color/transparent".
The complete code would look like this.
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:gravity="bottom">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/pink_application" />
        <size android:height="2dp" />
    </shape>
</item>


I just edited the answer by adding 1 more method. You can try it.
